# Eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the gate $U_a:|s\rangle\mapsto|sa \bmod N\rangle$

Tags: mathematics, textbook-and-exercises, shors-algorithm

I'm studying Shor algorithm. This is a demostration about the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $U_a$ gate:

[image]

Can somebody explain me from the third step to the last?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the state
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}\sum_{s=0}^{r-1}e^{-2\pi i\frac{k}{r}(s+1)}|a^{s+1}\text{ mod }N\rangle.
$$
Perform a change of variable $p=s+1$ so this simply reads
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}\sum_{p=1}^{r}e^{-2\pi i\frac{k}{r}p}|a^p\text{ mod }N\rangle.
$$
Now consider for a moment that $p=r$ term,
$$
e^{-2\pi i\frac{k}{r}r}|a^r\text{ mod }N\rangle=|a^r\text{ mod }N\rangle.
$$
By definition, $a^r\equiv 1\text{ mod }N$, which we could also write as $a^0$. Hence, this term is exactly the same as using $p=0$ instead. Thus, the state has become
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}\sum_{p=0}^{r-1}e^{-2\pi i\frac{k}{r}p}|a^p\text{ mod }N\rangle,
$$
which *is* $|w_k\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I forgot to add more details (Next time I should write "from the second step") : why at start there's this exponantial (positive) outside the summation and why the "s" in the exponational inside summation became "(s+1)" ?

Comment: because those two things cancel.

Comment: Really, thank you!